Change pdf link type from URI to GoToR
while exporting document from Word application to pdf, links in the document are exported as URI(i.e. file://...../other_doc.pdf). In order to validate them somewhere else I need the links to be of "Go to remote" type - according to ISO 32000-1:2008 - https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf
Links generated by Word document look like this:
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 387.75 627.78 440.07 652.75] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(m1/m1-toc.pdf) >>/StructParent 1>>

I need them to conform to 12.6.4.3 in the above mentioned standard. However when I try to change it to something like this:
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 387.75 695.68 440.07 720.65] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/GoToR/F (m1/m1-toc.pdf)/D [ 0 /Fit] >>/StructParent 1>>

It opens ok in Acrobat Reader but validator software (Lorenz eValidator by the way) says that the file is corrupted. I tried multiple space/no-space combination with attributes - nothing works. This is one of few items in the ISO standard, that doesn't have an example that I can rip off.
It is all part of the Nees procedure, if you want some non-technical context. It has to do with medicinal product registration and the registrar uses Lorenz, so I can't change that.
Thank you for any insights.

Are you just editing this file in a text editor? Then you need to reprocess it to fix up the byte offsets.

And if you have to manipulate multiple PDFs, writing a program using some general purpose PDF library likely would make the process more secure and faster

There are potentially 3 problems with your coding of the PDF action.
Basically it is correct. However validators can be very pedantic without explaining why. So if you consider what differences may be need we can try variations like this where  your coding attempt is 5 0 obj and the likely desired is 6 0 obj.
Here I have flagged object 5 off (false) but 6 as normal. you could use that for compliance testing.
%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj<</Pages 2 0 R/Type/Catalog>>endobj
2 0 obj<</Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]/Type/Pages>>endobj
3 0 obj<</Annots[5 0 R 6 0 R]/Contents 4 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page>>endobj
4 0 obj<</Length 0>>stream
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj<</Subtype/Link/Rect[387.75 695.68 440.07 720.65]/BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/GoToR/F(m1/m1-toc.pdf)/D [ 0 /Fit]>>/StructParent 1>>endobj
6 0 obj<</Subtype/Link/Rect[387.75 627.78 440.07 652.75]/BS<</W 0>>/F 4/P 3 0 R/A<</S/GoToR/F<</Type/Filespec/UF(m1/m1-toc.pdf)/F(m1/m1-toc.pdf)>>/D[0/Fit]>>/StructParent 1>>
endobj

xref
0 7
0000000001 65536 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000052 00000 n 
0000000101 00000 n 
0000000213 00000 n 
0000000257 00000 f 
0000000407 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 7/Root 1 0 R/ID[<44C21B401904A6800FA7ED30CE3BD912><BC2D3D1187A744B759304A4C122094FE>]>>
startxref
590
%%EOF

What are the differences and why?

/P 3 0 R is a linkback to the /Parent page
/Type/Action should not be needed but you need to double check if the validator expects it outside >> before or after /StructParent 1 but the object "Type" is generally a /Type/Annot!
Most specific to a Version 1.7+ PDF is that the /F should be double /Filespec entry ! /F<</Type/Filespec/UF(m1/m1-toc.pdf)/F(m1/m1-toc.pdf)>> see section 7.11.3 in your copy of Adobe specification.

As mentioned in comments, the runtime decimal XREF addresses, will all need checking by simply save the file using a "-clean" command, or simply use Acrobat Reader to "save as" could also fix those when closing the file.
Finally the "Validator" may NOT allow for relative subfolder files, since that needs access to a different system resource. It is best to use sibling files in one folder, not relative address as if a child generation.
